# How to send an image from background thread to the UI thread using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask to download an image and want to send the downloaded image to the UI thread. Here is the code for it.

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Drawable>{

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(URL... imgURL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream in;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Drawable d;
        try {
            //in = (InputStream) imgURL[0].getContent();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgURL[0].openConnection().getInputStream());
             d =(Drawable)new BitmapDrawable(bitmap); 
             return d;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }       
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `doInBackround()` is executed the returned value will be passed to `onPostExecute()` in your `AsynkTask`, so you should override the `onPostExecute()` method, and there you will receive your `Drawable`. Note that `onPostExecute()` and `onPreExecute()` are run on the UI Thread so you are able to modify/update the UI from this 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask
    {

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Url... url) {
        Bitmap b = 
                             // do some bitmap downloader code from web url  

        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

        imageView.setImageBitmap(image); 

    }
}
```

chek out this code because U cannot set image from doInBackGround()....

But still if u want to set it there are 2 ways.

1. use OnProgressUpdate() method on this thread or
2. try method Activity.runOnUiThread(){} thro' which it will interact with UI thread